# Voltage control for MT3608 / TP4056

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, raspberry-pi, step-up

I'm looking for powering up the Raspberry Pi by a few 18650.

It looks like MT3608+TP4056 are somewhat cheap/common way of managing LiPo batteries as a backup power.

I checked the specs and looks like MT3608 has a potentiometer to calibrate the output voltage - I read it as that there's no voltage stabilizer. So if a battery voltage drops by 0.5V - that will essentially make RPi unstable because of undervoltage.

What would be a better DIY alternative to have a power supply of 4 x 18650 batteries to supply RPi 5V/2A for extended period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MT3608 should be fine. It is a boost voltage regulator.  It *does regulate the output voltage*.  The datasheet says it will operate down to 2V input:
[image]
https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf

Comment: thanks for the comment, I got another question - I plugged in a battery with `3.3V` on it and then adjusted the output of `MT3608` to `5V`. Then I plugged another battery with `3.1V` output - and the output voltage was equal to `4.7V`. Am I understanding it properly that `MT3608` will regulate the **steadily decreasing** voltage with the **gradual** drop over time, but if it is switched off and then on - it will pick up whatever is the input voltage remaining on the battery and simply multiply it?

Comment: @jdevelop Hmm, from reading the datasheet and the graph in my answer, the Vout should not go below 5V.  The way this boost regulator works is 2Vin->5Vout, 3Vin->5Vout, 4Vin->5Vout. Your's may be defective. Double check your connections.

Comment: @jdevelop Also, what load do you have on it?  How many amps are you pulling?  Looks like it starts to fall off at around 1amp for 5Vout.

Comment: @jdevelop If you want to give the Pi a full 2Amps, then this is *not* the regulator for you, and yes 12V with a buck mode is probably a better idea for that.

Comment: thanks - I checked another device and it seems to work as expected for 2V and 3V of input I am getting `5V` as expected. Thanks again!